# How do I disable bouncing on ScrollView in Xamarin Forms for iOS?

Tags: xamarin.forms

I'm using a ScrollView in Xamarin Forms and on iOS, the scrollview bounces (often too far) when you hit the top or the bottom. My understanding is this is default iOS behavior? Is there a way I can disable this so there is no bounce on scroll?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Yes, disabling the bouncing effect is possible. But you will need to create a [Custom Renderer](https://developer.xamarin.com/guides/xamarin-forms/custom-renderer/).

In your specific case, you have to use [`ScrollViewRenderer`](https://developer.xamarin.com/guides/xamarin-forms/custom-renderer/renderers/#Layouts) as a base class for your custom renderer. Then, in your custom renderer, you can simply set [`Bounces`](https://developer.xamarin.com/api/property/MonoTouch.UIKit.UIScrollView.Bounces/) to `false`.

An example of a Custom Renderer can be found [here](https://developer.xamarin.com/guides/xamarin-forms/custom-renderer/entry/). Your result should look something like this:

**PCL:**

```
public class CustomScrollView : ScrollView
{
    public CustomScrollView() {}
}
```

**iOS:**

```
[assembly: ExportRenderer(typeof(CustomScrollView), typeof(CustomScrollViewRenderer))]
namespace Test.iOS
{
    public class CustomScrollViewRenderer : ScrollViewRenderer
    {
        protected override void OnElementChanged(VisualElementChangedEventArgs e)
        {
            base.OnElementChanged(e);
            Bounces = false;
        }
    }
}
```

On Android, you will need to implement a Custom Renderer as well which simply does nothing.

Comment: @Demitrian There's no need for a custom renderer that doesn't do anything. The default will suffice.